# Ubuntu 16.04 stopped to see updates from third-party repositories

Tags: apt, updates, repository, synaptic

I have several third party repositories configured in my Ubuntu 16.04 instance. For example I have this [https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/vim](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/vim) for latest vim versions. It was working several years without issues but since the end of September 2020 my Ubuntu seems to stop seeing any updates in those repositories.

Now I have vim version `2:8.2.1767-0york0~16.04` installed but from the link above it seems I should have version `2:8.2.1897-0york0~16.04`.

I also have https://apt.llvm.org/xenial repository which used to provide new versions almost daily and now I see nothing for months.

I tried to run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. These commands output their usual stuff which looks good and there are no error messages. All third party repositories are checked but no updates are seen.

Any tips on how to debug this are welcome.

**Update:** output of the `apt policy vim-gtk`

```
vim-gtk:
  Installed: 2:8.2.1767-0york0~16.04
  Candidate: 2:8.2.1767-0york0~16.04
  Version table:
 *** 2:8.2.1767-0york0~16.04 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
     2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt policy vim` to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see at the PPA [web site](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/vim/+build/20181853), packages for `amd64` have not been built.

So you can't install `vim` from that PPA.

Generally it is up to a PPA maintainer to build packages for specific Ubuntu releases.

Comment: Thanks, it seems amd64 was not built due to some build issue. I also have similar problem with apt.llvm.org - will try to figure it out myself.